# how to load image on SSR and show on page mount ? -NextJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

So I need when the page load my photo already be there how can I do this ?

I will appreciate some help I have no idea how to do this.

```js
import Image from 'next/image';

<div>
        <Image
          src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
          width="800"
          height="400"
        />
</div>
```

Comment: add the props loading="eager" on the image component

Answer (score 1):

Add priority prop. Wouldnt recommend using `loading="eager"`

You can read about the priority prop on the docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority

Can also read why not to use the loading eager setting - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loading

```
<Image
    src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    width="800"
    height="400"
    priority={true}
/>
```